# Union of denumerable sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In the book *Undergraduate Analysis* by Lang, we have the following theorem and proof:

> *Theorem*. If S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, . . . are a sequence of sets, each of
> wich is finite or denumerable, then the union S<sub>1</sub> $\bigcup$
> S<sub>2</sub> $\bigcup$ . . . is finite or denumerable.
>
> *Proof*. Each finite set is contained in some denumerable set, so that the statement follows from Propositions 4.1 and 4.6.

For completeness, here is the definition of denumerable set and propositions Lang mentions in the proof:

> **Definition.** A set S is said to be denumerable if there is a bijection of S into **Z<sup>+</sup>**.
>
> **Proposition 4.1.** Let D be an infinite subset of **Z<sup>+</sup>**. Then D is denumerable, and in fact there is a unique enumeration of D,
> namely { k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, . . . } such that k<sub>1</sub>
> < k<sub>2</sub> < . . . < k<sub>n</sub> < k<sub>n+1</sub> < . . .
> <sub>.</sub>
>
> **Proposition 4.6.** Let { D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub>, . . . } be a
> sequence of denumerable sets. Let S be the union of all sets
> D<sub>*i*</sub> (*i* = 1, 2, . . .). Then S is denumerable.

I have two questions about this proof:

1 - How so any finite set is contained in a denumerable set? By definition, any denumerable set is infinite, so if I restrict myself to a finite universe of objects (for instance, the universe where every object is a character of a finite alphabet), then there is no denumerable set.

2 - How can Proposition 4.1 and Proposition 4.6 be used to prove the Theorem? Both propositions assert some property of infinite sets, while the Theorem is dealing with both infinite and finite sets, so there is no immediate correspondence between the propositions and the Theorem.

Comment: Where in the definition does it say that a denumerable set is infinite?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur  "a bijection of $S$ into $\mathbf Z^+$"

Comment: @Henry I somehow misread that as injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to a finite universe of objects, then you cannot consider $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and denumerable sets and then this question does not make sense : we don't do analysis with such universes. So, you cannot do such a restriction for the kind of mathematics you consider here. Each finite set $B$ is in bijection with some (finite) subset $C$ of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and the set $B$ is included in $B \cup (\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus C)$ and the set $B \cup (\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus C)$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{Z}^+$, so each finite set is included in some denumerable set.

Now, indeed, it is not immediate how we could apply Proposition 4.6 because we need to consider a sequence of denumerable sets. Since each finite set $S$ is included in some denumerable set $D$, for each $i$, there exists a denumerable set $D_i$ such that $S_i$ is included in $D_i$. Applying the [axiom of denumerable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice), we can then deduce that there exists a sequence $(D_i)_i$ of denumerable sets such that, for each $i$, the set $S_i$ is included in $D_i$. Now we can apply Proposition 4.6 to deduce that the union of the $D$ sets is denumerable. Moreover the union of the $S$ sets is included in the union of the $D$ sets and, thus, by Proposition 4.1, if the union of the $S$ sets is infinite (otherwise, it is finite and we are done) then it is denumerable.

Comment: The is a really clever idea: build $B \cup (\mathbb{Z}^+ \setminus C)$ as "copy" of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and then conclude it is denumerable, because it a copy of the positive integers. I hadn't thought about it, but it fits perfectly with Proposition 4.1. Lang does not explicit mentions the Axiom of countable choice, but considering ZFC is the standard model of set theory and that the Axiom of Choice implies the Axiom of countable choice, then it is safe to take this approach (also it is pretty intuitive to build a sequence of sets, even without thinking directly of the Axiom of countable choice).

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I suspect that without being explicit about it, Lang is using the Zermelo-Fraenkel axiom. In which case it is True, because you have the existence of denumerable set using the axiom of infinity and then you can do union between any set.

For the second part of your question, Proposition 4.1 tells you that a subset of a denumerable set is either finite of denumerable, on the other hand the argument in the proof of the Theorem combined with Proposition 4.6 tells you that the union of the S sets is included in denumerable set.

Comment: I think there a couple of problems with this point of view:

1 - The Axiom of Infinity guarantees the existence of an infinite set, but this doesn't necessarily implies that every finite set is contained in this infinite set. For instance, consider a universe with only three objects: { a, b, c }. Then using the Axiom of Infinite, we know that the following object is a set and is infinite: **I** = { ∅, { ∅ }, { ∅, { ∅ } }, . . . }. Note that a ∉ I, b ∉ I and c ∉ I and so { a, b, c } ⊄ I.

Comment: 2 - Actually a denumerable set can't be finite by definition: A set S is said to be denumerable if there is a bijection of S into the positive integers.  So Proposition 4.1 can only be invoked in infinite subset of a denumerable set.

Comment: With respect to the first comment, that is why you need to do the union afterward with the initial set, so that you get an infinite set that indeed contains the original one